# Trying to create hierarchy between 3-4 custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to think of a way to create a certain hierarchy between several post types.

I was looking at `term_taxonomy` table, and its seem to have the capability to achieve that.

I have a feature to create custom post type on the fly why you can select a parent from the other post type. those parents will have several uses. they could serve as categories authors or whatever other name the user has gave it.

i have several templates that the user can chose from. in those templates this hierarchy comes to life.

I know i can do it ugly - with either outside table or custom fields. i was wondering if there's a more "WP way" to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try just putting the ID of the parent into `post_parent`? This does not depend on the post type.

Comment: yea i know i this can be done in that way. setting the post parent. and then useing my own relation table. i am wondering if there's a WP way